# hibernate query question

Tags: hibernate

I'm having a Hibernate query problem, basically it goes like this ...

I have a User object that has an associated set of Class objects.  Class objects have a startDate (a java.util.Date).

In my UI the User has a display only startDate which is the the startDate of the earliest class.

How do I build a Hibernate query that will return a list of Users that have a start date within a range?

Originally I was thinking it would be something like ...

```
"from User u where :beginRange < u.startDate < :endRange"
```

... but the problem is the u.startDate is not persisted in the database, it's dynamically determined for presentation only.

Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this should work :

```
from User u where (select min(c.startDate) from Clazz c where c.user.id = u.id) between :beginRange and :endRange
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT u 
FROM User u JOIN u.classes c 
HAVING MIN(c.startDate) BETWEEN :beginRange AND :endRange
GROUP BY u.id, ...
```